# react native - store object on device and upload on internet reconnection

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I’ve looked at the storage api’s for both react-native and expo and I’m struggling to find a suitable way to structure my app.

I’ve made an app for my workplace in which we scan equipment and record the data. At the moment I’m using firebase to upload the data and store on their servers.

My boss has asked whether we can implement a way of storing the data locally if the user has no access to wifi and then upload the data upon internet reconnection.

I’m not sure where to start with this. I understand that I can use NetInfo and add an event listener to monitor the connection. However I’m not sure how I would persist any scanned data with the opening and closing of the app and such.

If anyone could help point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated it.

Thanks

Comment: You can check AsyncStorage

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html

Comment: I've seen asyncstorage and from what I understand it would only be key value pairs where the value is a string? I need to store objects.

Also, if someone can help me with how I would structure this as I'm not sure where to start

Comment: You can always convert objects to strings using JSON.stringify and convert them vice verse by JSON.parse

Comment: Are you using firebase database? Its real time and it has offline by default, it updates when reconnects automatically.

Comment: Thanks @user3696882.

Comment: @parohy, I am using the firebase firestore. Yes, I've seen this, but I think it clears once the app is closed and reopened. I think it only persists the data during the session

Comment: Give it a try. It may be just a question of adding an extra line to initialization. Test it without connection.

Comment: I'll take a look. Thanks @parohy

Comment: Going through your question a thought popped into my mind. This is just a idea and i have not tried yet. 

Can you have a file in your project directory like "recordData.json" which contains equipment data(json) wrapped inside an array. We add this data in absence of internet. 

By using NetInfo and eventListener, when connected to a network, we can make a call to firebase with that data.

Can this be possible?